# Implementing Wireless Sensor Network using Raspberri Pi3

Tags: python, linux, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I am supposed to write the Energy sensed routing algorithm for Wireless Sensor Network using Python. The node hardware are Raspberry Pi 3 boards. Is there any way to manipulate the wifi hardware using python (OS will be raspbian or noobs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module  for scanning and connecting to wifi networks on linux [wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Module for accessing to a wireless network card's capabilities 
using the Linux Wireless Extensions 
[python-wifi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-wifi)

Module for packet manipulation [scapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scapy).